# Why do no Typescript commands appear in Visual Studio Code command palette?

Tags: typescript, ide, visual-studio-code

I ran  `npm install -g typescript`, and I get in npm:

```
$ tsc -v
Version 2.7.2
```

I have a jsconfig.json file in a folder open. When I enter in the command palette`TypeScript: Select TypeScript Version` suggested in the [getting started here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript),
I get no commands. Is there an extension I need to download?

[image]

Comment: open a .ts file and check what you have at the bottom bar on the right. ts version is right before the 'smiley face'

Comment: @Vega I have 2.7.2 and you fixed it. You have to have a typescript file open in order for the commands to show up in the palette.

Comment: @Vega +2.......

Comment: More precisely, a *.ts file must be opened and it must be the active tab in order for Typescript commands to show in the palette (VSCode Version: 1.74.3)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to have a typescript file open in order for the commands to show up in the palette. Up vote [vega](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5468463/vega) if you found this useful.

Comment: That is very nice of you :)